Find a continuous increasing function $T:(0,1)\to (0,\infty)$ s.t. $Y=T(X)$ has p.d.f $g(y)=\frac{2}{(y+1)^3}$

Let $X$ be uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$. Find a continuous increasing function $T:(0,1)\to (0,\infty)$ s.t. $Y=T(X)$ has p.d.f $g(y)=\frac{2}{(y+1)^3}, y\gt 0$

My approach
I believe that for one-to-one functions $Y=T(X)$ that $g(y)=f(s(y))\cdot|s'(y)|$ where $s(y)=T^{-1}(y)$
From $X$ being uniform on $(0,1)$, I should have:
$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
 1&,\ 0\lt x\lt 1 \\
 0&,\text{otherwise} \\
\end{cases}
$
So, $$g(y)=1\cdot|s'(y)|$$
$$\implies g(y)=\frac{d}{dy}[T^{-1}(y)]$$
$$\implies G(y)=T^{-1}(y)$$
$$\implies \frac{-1}{(y+1)^2}=T^{-1}(y)$$
Now what do I do to find $T(X)$? If I solve for inverse functions in the usual way I get $T(X)=\pm \sqrt{-\frac{1}{X}}-1$. But this is not a continuous increasing function.

Do you know the probability integral transform? This is just the inverse of that.

@StubbornAtom I found the theorem in my textbook: "Let $X$ have a continuous c.d.f. $F$, and let $Y = F (X)$.
(This transformation from $X$ to $Y$ is called the probability integral transformation.)
The distribution of $Y$ is the uniform distribution on the interval $[0, 1]$. How does this help?

As I said, you need the inverse of the probability integral transform. That is, solving for $X$ from $Y=F(X)$.

@StubbornAtom I both don't understand why I'm wrong, or how to do that. The theorem doesn't have an obvious (to me) application when $X$ is uniform on $(0,1)$.

You were nearly done:
$$g(y)=\frac{d}{dy}[T^{-1}(y)]$$
$$\implies \frac{-1}{(y+1)^2}-\frac{-1}{(0+1)^2}=T^{-1}(y)$$
$$\implies \frac{-1}{(T(x)+1)^2}+1=x$$
$$\implies T(x)=\frac1{\sqrt{1-x}}-1.$$
